# How do I transform data to long when the time indicator does not start from column 1

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data which gives me headache

EDIT: Updated column names and data to better represent my data as I did not have the skill to apply the answers already brought fourth (I am sorry)

```
dat3 <- data.frame(
    sex = c("F","F","F", "F","M","M","M", "M","TOT","TOT","TOT","TOT","F","F","F", "F","M","M","M", "M","TOT","TOT","TOT","TOT"),
    age = c(rep("Y70-74",12),rep("Y75-79",12)),
    geo = c("UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA","POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA","POL"),
    "2021W3" = c(5,3,7,5,8,2,6,5,13,5,13,10,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2021W2" = c(6,8,4,5,9,1,0,4,15,9,12,9,   1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2021W1" = c(8,7,9,2,1,2,3,6,9, 9,12,8 ,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2020W52"= c(1,2,8,2,5,1,2,4,6, 3,10,6,   1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2020W51"= c(4,4,3,6,4,5,1,0,9, 5,4, 6 ,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2020W50"= c(3,6,3,5,2,1,2,5,5, 7,5, 10,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5))
   
    dat3
   sex    age geo X2021W3 X2021W2 X2021W1 X2020W52 X2020W51 X2020W50
1    F Y70-74  UK       5       6       8        1        4        3
2    F Y70-74 GER       3       8       7        2        4        6
3    F Y70-74 FRA       7       4       9        8        3        3
4    F Y70-74 POL       5       5       2        2        6        5
5    M Y70-74  UK       8       9       1        5        4        2
6    M Y70-74 GER       2       1       2        1        5        1
7    M Y70-74 FRA       6       0       3        2        1        2
8    M Y70-74 POL       5       4       6        4        0        5
9  TOT Y70-74  UK      13      15       9        6        9        5
10 TOT Y70-74 GER       5       9       9        3        5        7
11 TOT Y70-74 FRA      13      12      12       10        4        5
12 TOT Y70-74 POL      10       9       8        6        6       10
13   F Y75-79  UK       1       1       1        1        1        1
14   F Y75-79 GER       2       2       2        2        2        2
15   F Y75-79 FRA       3       3       3        3        3        3
16   F Y75-79 POL       4       4       4        4        4        4
17   M Y75-79  UK       1       1       1        1        1        1
18   M Y75-79 GER       1       1       1        1        1        1
19   M Y75-79 FRA       1       1       1        1        1        1
20   M Y75-79 POL       1       1       1        1        1        1
21 TOT Y75-79  UK       2       2       2        2        2        2
22 TOT Y75-79 GER       3       3       3        3        3        3
23 TOT Y75-79 FRA       4       4       4        4        4        4
24 TOT Y75-79 POL       5       5       5        5        5        5
   
   
  
   dat4 <- data.frame(
     Time = rep(c("2020W50","2020W51","2020W52","20210W1","2021W2","2021W3"),4),
     geo = c(rep("UK",6),rep("GER",6), rep("FRA",6),rep("POL",6)),
     "FY70-74" = c(5,6,8,1,4,3,3,8,7,2,4,6,7,4,9,8,3,3,5,5,2,2,6,5),
     "MY70-74" = c(8,9,1,5,4,2,2,1,2,1,5,1,6,0,3,2,1,2,5,4,6,4,0,5),
     "TY70-74" = c(13,15,9,6,8,5,5,9,9,3,9,7,13,4,12,10,4,5,10,9,8,6,6,10),
     "FY75-79" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),
     "MY75-74" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
     "TY75-79" = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5))
   

>    dat4
      Time geo FY70.74 MY70.74 TY70.74 FY75.79 MY75.74 TY75.79
1  2020W50  UK       5       8      13       1       1       2
2  2020W51  UK       6       9      15       1       1       2
3  2020W52  UK       8       1       9       1       1       2
4  20210W1  UK       1       5       6       1       1       2
5   2021W2  UK       4       4       8       1       1       2
6   2021W3  UK       3       2       5       1       1       2
7  2020W50 GER       3       2       5       2       1       3
8  2020W51 GER       8       1       9       2       1       3
9  2020W52 GER       7       2       9       2       1       3
10 20210W1 GER       2       1       3       2       1       3
11  2021W2 GER       4       5       9       2       1       3
12  2021W3 GER       6       1       7       2       1       3
13 2020W50 FRA       7       6      13       3       1       4
14 2020W51 FRA       4       0       4       3       1       4
15 2020W52 FRA       9       3      12       3       1       4
16 20210W1 FRA       8       2      10       3       1       4
17  2021W2 FRA       3       1       4       3       1       4
18  2021W3 FRA       3       2       5       3       1       4
19 2020W50 POL       5       5      10       4       1       5
20 2020W51 POL       5       4       9       4       1       5
21 2020W52 POL       2       6       8       4       1       5
22 20210W1 POL       2       4       6       4       1       5
23  2021W2 POL       6       0       6       4       1       5
24  2021W3 POL       5       5      10       4       1       5
>
```

EDIT: I am terribly sorry I could not picture how I wanted my data set but I know now - I want three sex categories "Female", Male", "Total" spread out across all age ranges:

"LT5 Y5-9   Y14-19  Y20-24  Y25-29  Y30-34  Y35-39  Y40-44  Y45-49  Y50-54  Y55-59  Y60-64  Y65-69  Y70-74  Y75-79  Y80-84  Y85-89  OT90"

So that within each age category: Female + Male = TOTAL

NOTE: My **TIME** index has to start from the first date - 2020W50 - so I need to somehow flip the order of columns before I `melt`

In my example the numbers and dates are now mixed up. I want the correct order of dates (first to last with the right numbers attached of course)

Also I don't know why there are "X'es" behind my column names. Also R changed "70-74" to "70.74". Don't know why.

Comment: I would try to use some t() and merge() functions.

Comment: Are the Xs and - happening in the original data or just in your example?

Comment: Also in the original data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

n <- 1129 # change this to the number accordingly   
names_list <- as.character()
names_list[1:n] <- str_c("Week",seq(1:n)) %>% unlist()

datLong <- datWide %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = names_list,
    names_to = "Time") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "sex")
# A tibble: 24 x 6
   age    geo   Time      F     M   TOT
   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Y70-74 UK    Week1     5     8    13
 2 Y70-74 UK    Week2     6     9    15
 3 Y70-74 UK    Week3     8     1     9
 4 Y70-74 UK    Week4     1     5     6
 5 Y70-74 UK    Week5     4     4     9
 6 Y70-74 UK    Week6     3     2     5
 7 Y70-74 GER   Week1     3     2     5
 8 Y70-74 GER   Week2     8     1     9
 9 Y70-74 GER   Week3     7     2     9
10 Y70-74 GER   Week4     2     1     3
# ... with 14 more rows
```

UPDATE:
R is putting Xs before the date columns because R variables 'should' begin with a character and not a number.
The column names are being changed because the - character is a non-standard object name character. To fix both of these issues add `check.names=FALSE` to the end of the data frame constructor:

```
dat3 <- data.frame(
  sex = c("F","F","F", "F","M","M","M", "M","TOT","TOT","TOT","TOT","F","F","F", "F","M","M","M", "M","TOT","TOT","TOT","TOT"),
  age = c(rep("Y70-74",12),rep("Y75-79",12)),
  geo = c("UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA","POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA","POL"),
  "2021W3" = c(5,3,7,5,8,2,6,5,13,5,13,10,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
  "2021W2" = c(6,8,4,5,9,1,0,4,15,9,12,9,   1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
  "2021W1" = c(8,7,9,2,1,2,3,6,9, 9,12,8 ,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
  "2020W52"= c(1,2,8,2,5,1,2,4,6, 3,10,6,   1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
  "2020W51"= c(4,4,3,6,4,5,1,0,9, 5,4, 6 ,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
  "2020W50"= c(3,6,3,5,2,1,2,5,5, 7,5, 10,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
  check.names = FALSE)

dat3
   sex    age geo  2021W3  2021W2  2021W1  2020W52  2020W51  2020W50
1    F Y70-74  UK       5       6       8        1        4        3
2    F Y70-74 GER       3       8       7        2        4        6
3    F Y70-74 FRA       7       4       9        8        3        3
4    F Y70-74 POL       5       5       2        2        6        5
5    M Y70-74  UK       8       9       1        5        4        2
6    M Y70-74 GER       2       1       2        1        5        1
7    M Y70-74 FRA       6       0       3        2        1        2
8    M Y70-74 POL       5       4       6        4        0        5
9  TOT Y70-74  UK      13      15       9        6        9        5
10 TOT Y70-74 GER       5       9       9        3        5        7
11 TOT Y70-74 FRA      13      12      12       10        4        5
12 TOT Y70-74 POL      10       9       8        6        6       10
13   F Y75-79  UK       1       1       1        1        1        1
```

This allows you to begin column names with numbers but it is not recommended and should be avoided where possible.

To change the format from dat3 to dat4 you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
names_list <- colnames(dat3[4:length(dat3)])
datNew <- dat3 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = names_list, names_to = "Time") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("sex","age"), )
datNew <- arrange(datNew, desc("Time"))
datNew

# A tibble: 24 x 8
   geo   Time   `F_Y70-74` `M_Y70-74` `TOT_Y70-74` `F_Y75-79` `M_Y75-79` `TOT_Y75-79`
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 UK    2021W3          5          8           13          1          1            2
 2 GER   2021W3          3          2            5          2          1            3
 3 FRA   2021W3          7          6           13          3          1            4
 4 POL   2021W3          5          5           10          4          1            5
 5 UK    2021W2          6          9           15          1          1            2
 6 GER   2021W2          8          1            9          2          1            3
 7 FRA   2021W2          4          0           12          3          1            4
 8 POL   2021W2          5          4            9          4          1            5
 9 UK    2021W1          8          1            9          1          1            2
10 GER   2021W1          7          2            9          2          1            3
# ... with 14 more rows
```

which will create the relevant columns and order the rows by date in descending order.

These columns must be called using inverted commas because of the '-' character that R interprets as minus.

```
> datNew$`F_Y70-74`
 [1] 5 6 8 1 4 3 3 8 7 2 4 6 7 4 9 8 3 3 5 5 2 2 6 5
> datNew$F_Y70-74
numeric(0)
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `F_Y70`.
```

I would recommend changing these to underscores.

Comment: I have 1129 weeks in total (every week from 2000-2021). How do I do that?

Comment: I have adjusted the code so now you can add an arbitrary number of weeks by changing the n value.

Comment: Hi Jared, I am terribly sorry but my example was not satisfactory so I changed it around. Would you be so kind as to take a look at my updated data examples? Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Thanks for updating Jared. Is there a way for me to switch the order of the time indices? Maybe if I could somehow switch columns  2021W3 and 2020W50 before using dplyr?

Comment: Sorry, the code above should arrange the rows from newest to oldest. The output I posted was from before it was rearranged. I will amend the output above.

Answer (score 2):

If you like the `data.table` package, here is one way to do it:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(datWide)
datLong <- datWide[, melt(.SD , id.vars = c("sex", "age", "geo"), variable.name = "Time")
                   ][, dcast(.SD, age + geo + Time ~ sex, value.var = "value")]

datLong
```

Sample output:

```
      age geo  Time F M TOT
 1: Y70-74 FRA Week1 7 6  13
 2: Y70-74 FRA Week2 4 0  12
 3: Y70-74 FRA Week3 9 3  12
 4: Y70-74 FRA Week4 8 2  10
 5: Y70-74 FRA Week5 3 1   4
```

With this approach you only specify your `id.vars`, regardless of how many weeks you have.

Comment: Hello Markus and canovasjm, I am sorry but I updated my example to better show my true data file. I would really appreciate if you read my edits and took a look at my post again.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `dcast` + `melt`

```
dcast(
  melt(setDT(datWide),
    id.var = 1:3,
    variable.name = "Time"
  ),
  Time + geo + age ~ sex
)[order(-geo, Time)]
```

gives

```
     Time geo    age F M TOT
 1: Week1  UK Y70-74 5 8  13
 2: Week2  UK Y70-74 6 9  15
 3: Week3  UK Y70-74 8 1   9
 4: Week4  UK Y70-74 1 5   6
 5: Week5  UK Y70-74 4 4   9
 6: Week6  UK Y70-74 3 2   5
 7: Week1 POL Y70-74 5 5  10
 8: Week2 POL Y70-74 5 4   9
 9: Week3 POL Y70-74 2 6   8
10: Week4 POL Y70-74 2 4   6
11: Week5 POL Y70-74 6 0   6
12: Week6 POL Y70-74 5 5  10
13: Week1 GER Y70-74 3 2   5
14: Week2 GER Y70-74 8 1   9
15: Week3 GER Y70-74 7 2   9
16: Week4 GER Y70-74 2 1   3
17: Week5 GER Y70-74 4 5   5
18: Week6 GER Y70-74 6 1   7
19: Week1 FRA Y70-74 7 6  13
20: Week2 FRA Y70-74 4 0  12
21: Week3 FRA Y70-74 9 3  12
22: Week4 FRA Y70-74 8 2  10
23: Week5 FRA Y70-74 3 1   4
24: Week6 FRA Y70-74 3 2   5
     Time geo    age F M TOT
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you so much for your time. Could I get you to read my edited post and update your answer?